# How to prevent infinite loop in my React code when using setState inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Please check the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hamilton-k1nzs

Moment I run the code I am getting an infinite loop, you can check the console to see how the entries increase exponentially. And eventually the website crashes.

I have a state variable like this:

```
const [checkbox, setCheckBox] = useState({});
```

Then I am calling a function inside useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    createCheckbox();
  });
```

This is the createCheckbox function:

```
const createCheckbox = () => {
    let checkboxObj = {};
    rows.forEach((e) => {
      checkboxObj[e.id] = false;
    });
    setCheckBox(checkboxObj);
  };
```

I have a console.log at line 76 to showcase the problem. It is console.log(checkbox)

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: My first question when looking at this, is why do you need to createCheckbox() inside a useEffect ?

Comment: The effect has no dependency and updates state, so result is render looping. Add a dependency. Check a condition ***on*** that dependency. When do you want `createCheckbox` to run?

Comment: @Spangle I have a codesandbox above. Basically I want to initialize the checkbox as empty/false on first load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

```
useEffect(() => {
  createCheckbox();
});
```

The `useEffect` hook has no dependency so it runs every time the component renders, and since the hook callback ultimately updates state, it triggers another render cycle. Rinse and repeat, ad nauseam (i.e. render looping).

## Solution

> Basically I want to initialize the checkbox as empty/false on first
> load.

You can use an `useEffect` with empty dependency array to run the effect once when the component mounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
  createCheckbox();
}, []);
```

Or use lazy state initialization function with the `useState` hook.

```
const [checkbox, setCheckBox] = useState(() => {
  let checkboxObj = {};
  rows.forEach((e) => {
    checkboxObj[e.id] = false;
  });
  return checkboxObj;
});
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-prevent-infinite-loop-in-my-react-code-when-using-setstate-inside-useeffe]

Comment: I ran the sandbox. For some reason when I click on the checkbox it is not getting selected though. But the infinite loop seems to be gone.

Comment: @Adam That wasn't part of the question, so I didn't debug any further than eliminating the render looping, but I don't mind taking a deeper look.

Comment: Thanks I will mark this as the answer anyway, and open the other one as a new question.

Comment: @Adam I think I've a resolution for the checkboxes not toggling. Have a link for your new question?

Comment: A minute. Making the questions now

Comment: This is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66237119/checkbox-not-toggling-in-react-with-material-ui

Answer (score 8):

Use a dependency array for `useEffect`. So this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    createCheckbox();
  });
```

Should be:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    createCheckbox();
  }, []);
```

[useEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), as you already know, accepts a dependency array as the second parameter. It will only run when any of the variables in the array change. When you run `useEffect` without the second parameter, it acts as componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate. So since you set a state in your dependency-less useEffect, the state change triggers it again and again thus creating an infinite loop of renders.

When calling `useEffect` with an empty dependency array, it will only run once on first render. And that's what you needed.