# Checkbox not toggling in React with Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I have a React code in which the checkbox is not toggling when I click on it.

This is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-kirch-q6p4h

I am initializing the checkbox state like this:

```
const [checkbox, setCheckBox] = useState(() => {
    let checkboxObj = {};

    rows.forEach((e) => {
      checkboxObj[e.id] = false;
    });
    return checkboxObj;
  });
```

We have a column array in which there is a function called customElement which contains the checkbox handler.

```
const columns = [
    {
      key: "Source_campname",
      title: "TS Camp Name",
      customElement: function (row) {
        console.log(checkbox);
        return (
          <FormControlLabel
            control={
              <Checkbox
                checked={checkbox[row.id]}
                key={row.id}
                onChange={() =>
                  handleChange(row.Source_campname, row.id, checkbox)
                }
                name={row.id}
              />
            }
            label={[row.Source_campname]}
          />
        );
      }
    },
    {
      key: "Tracker_campname",
      title: "TR Camp Name"
    }
  ];
```

Checkbox toggle is handled in the function below:

```
const handleChange = (name, campid) => {
    setCheckBox({ ...checkbox, [campid]: !checkbox[campid] });
  };
```

What is happening is that the checkbox is not toggling when I click on it. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug in on this a bit and after converting `handleChange` to use a functional state update

```
const handleChange = (name, campid) => {
  setCheckBox((checkbox) => ({
    ...checkbox,
    [campid]: !checkbox[campid]
  }));
};
```

to try and avoid any stale enclosures with the `columns` prop passed to `ThanosTable` I dug in on that component code to see if/how it handled re-enclosed checkbox values passed in the `columns` prop.

## Issue

The `columns` are stored in local state in the `visibleColumns` state and never again does `ThanosTable` look at and respond to changes on the `columns` prop.

## Solution

Add an `useEffect` to update the `visibleColumns` state when props update.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setVisibleColumns(
    !options.removeColumnsFeature &&
    options.showColumns &&
    options.showColumns.length
    ? [...columns.filter((x) => options.showColumns.includes(x.key))]
    : [...columns]
  )
}, [columns, options]);
```

[image: Edit checkbox-not-toggling-in-react-with-material-ui]

You can, and should, factor the common logic between the `visibleColumns` state initializer and effect callback.

Comment: Woah thanks for digging deep. I was trying everything I could in the main file, but could not find that the problem was present in the thanosTable2.js file. Its a library we built for handling tables. Great, thanks mate!

Comment: It solved another problem we had too. Which was that when we change page, or scroll the checkbox was getting unselected. I will mark the answer in 5 minutes, stackoverflow has a limit of 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the callback inside the `useState` declaration

[**Example Codesanbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-prevent-infinite-loop-in-my-react-code-when-using-setstate-inside-useeffe-forked-mwxr9)

```
const [checkbox, setCheckBox] = useState({});
```

Comment: `useState` initializer functions run only once, they don't overwrite anything. This just removes the initial state values and the table is essentially rendering uncontrolled inputs since no state is driving them, thus allowing the checkboxes to be toggled.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, the solution above worked but it did not solve the main problem that the state values were not updating as I wanted it to.

Comment: @Adam you haven't written anything about state problem. Your question related to common toggle issue